# How to automate Atom Editor in order to prepare the development environment?

Tags: command-line, automation, atom-editor

I work on a project which requires me to open several [Terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) tabs and start a process in each of these.

Is there a way to automate the opening of Terminal tabs and feeding the command prompt? That is, to automate the process of setting up the development environment using a script or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

`atom YourFileName.EXT` would open the `YourFileName.EXT` in the current opened atom editor window as tab, so you can write a bash/batch script to automate the process depending on what OS you are using.